# mongodb spark connector 10.2 error to stream data

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

i want to stream data from mongodb with spark and print them in console
i use mongodb connector 10.2.1 and pyspark 3.2.3 and mongodb 7
here is my code :

```
my_spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("myApp") \
.config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://mongoadmin:mongoadmin@localhost:27018/") \
.config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://mongoadmin:mongoadmin@localhost:27018/") \
.config("spark.version", "3.2.3")\
.config("spark.jars.packages", "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.13:10.2.1") \
.getOrCreate()

streamingDataFrame = (my_spark.readStream
                  .format("mongodb")
                  .option("database", "people")
                  .option("collection", "contacts")
                  .load()
                  )
dataStreamWriter = (streamingDataFrame.writeStream
                .trigger(continuous="1 second")
                .format("mongodb")
                .option("database", "people")
                .option("collection", "contacts2")
                .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpointDir")
                .outputMode("append")
                )
```

query = dataStreamWriter.start()

but i get error :

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.toAttributes()Lscala/collection/immutable/Seq;
> at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.schema.InternalRowToRowFunction.(InternalRowToRowFunction.java:46)
> at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.schema.RowToBsonDocumentConverter.(RowToBsonDocumentConverter.java:84)

i found it relates to version mismatched but i don't understand how to fix it because i try different version

i really apperciate any help